# SSRS: How does positioning work with images using AutoSize in containers?

Tags: xml, image, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have the following portion of XML in my RDL within a rectangle:

```
<ReportItems>
    <Image Name="Image180">
        <Height>0.00013333333333333in</Height>
        <Left>0.25in</Left>
        <Sizing>AutoSize</Sizing>
        <Source>Embedded</Source>
        <Top>0.0000000001in</Top>
        <Value>LinkName1</Value>
        <Width>1in</Width>
        <Style>
            <Border>
                <Style>None</Style>
            </Border>
            <PaddingLeft>0in</PaddingLeft>
            <PaddingRight>0in</PaddingRight>
            <PaddingTop>0in</PaddingTop>
            <PaddingBottom>0in</PaddingBottom>
        </Style>
    </Image>
    <Image Name="Image181">
        <Height>0.00035729166666667in</Height>
        <Left>0.25in</Left>
        <Sizing>AutoSize</Sizing>
        <Source>Embedded</Source>
        <Top>0.0128in</Top>
        <Value>LinkName2</Value>
        <Width>1in</Width>
        <ZIndex>1</ZIndex>
        <Style>
            <Border>
                <Style>None</Style>
            </Border>
            <PaddingLeft>0in</PaddingLeft>
            <PaddingRight>0in</PaddingRight>
            <PaddingTop>0in</PaddingTop>
            <PaddingBottom>0in</PaddingBottom>
        </Style>
    </Image>
    <Image Name="Image182">
        <Height>0.000159375in</Height>
        <Left>0.25in</Left>
        <Sizing>AutoSize</Sizing>
        <Source>Embedded</Source>
        <Top>0.0471in</Top>
        <Value>LinkName3</Value>
        <Width>1in</Width>
        <ZIndex>2</ZIndex>
        <Style>
            <Border>
                <Style>None</Style>
            </Border>
            <PaddingLeft>0in</PaddingLeft>
            <PaddingRight>0in</PaddingRight>
            <PaddingTop>0in</PaddingTop>
            <PaddingBottom>0in</PaddingBottom>
        </Style>
    </Image>
    <Image Name="Image183">
        <Height>0.00010104166666667in</Height>
        <Left>0.25in</Left>
        <Sizing>AutoSize</Sizing>
        <Source>Embedded</Source>
        <Top>0.0624in</Top>
        <Value>LinkName4</Value>
        <Width>1in</Width>
        <ZIndex>3</ZIndex>
        <Style>
            <Border>
                <Style>None</Style>
            </Border>
            <PaddingLeft>0in</PaddingLeft>
            <PaddingRight>0in</PaddingRight>
            <PaddingTop>0in</PaddingTop>
            <PaddingBottom>0in</PaddingBottom>
        </Style>
    </Image>
</ReportItems>
<KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
<Style>
    <Border>
        <Style>None</Style>
    </Border>
</Style>
```

Needless to say, LinkName1 just links to a base64 encoded image.

My issue with the above is that the first image doesn't appear. That is, unless I set its  value to 0 (remove it), in which case it appears after all the other images...

This has been boggling my mind for days now (well, this and the fact that the top position of the previous image in inches + the height of the previous image as the top position of the next image does not make the images butt up against each other...).

Could someone please tell me what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I don't know if this is an answer or not, but I was unsure whether to put it here, or in a comment and close the question.

I found the answer to my problem was to switch to points, and give the first image a different height than the following images (First image ended up with a height 1/4th the size of the actual image, and the following images ended up with a height 1/6912th the size of the actual image). I have no idea why this worked.